# "make: *** No targets. Stop." error

Tags: makefile

I've prepared the following makefile, to automatically clean-up all the temporary projects I want to delete:

```
.SUFFIXES : bye


#  The default action is to
#      remove the latest project, i was working at...
byebye :
    rm -rf "$(ls -1dt /projects/new_* | head -n1)"


#  Remove a specific project.
#  Run make from the command-line as 'make new_1_bye' etc.
%_bye :
    rm -rf /projects/$*
```

But, if I run make as:

```
$ make
```

I get:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

The `.SUFFIXES` line seems to cause the trouble.  Suffixes normally start with a dot (`.c`, for example).  Make appears to accept the suffix `bye`, but that means the line `byebye:` marks the start of a suffix rule, and the `%_bye` line is also a suffix rule.  That adds up to mean there are no targets cited in the `makefile`, hence the error message.

If you use `.SUFFIXES : .bye` instead, `make` is then happy with the makefile.